# Transposing without recursion

Tags: list, function, f#, transpose

How do I go about creating a function which will transpose a list without using recursion?

This is what I've gotten so far:

```
let lst = [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]]
let transpLstLst (lst: 'a list list) -> 'a list list =
    List.map List.head lst :: []
```

Which returns:

```
[[1;4;7]]
```

This is a long the lines of the output I want, but how do I go from that to being able to get to this output:

```
[[1;4;7];[2;5;8];[3;6;9]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very inefficient*, but it meets your requirements:

```ml
let transpose (matrix : List<List<_>>) =
    [
        if matrix.Length > 0 then
            assert(matrix |> List.distinctBy List.length |> List.length = 1)
            for i = 0 to matrix.[0].Length - 1 do
                yield [
                    for list in matrix do
                        yield list.[i]
                ]
    ]
```

Example:

```ml
let matrix = [[1; 2; 3]; [4; 5; 6]; [7; 8; 9]; [10; 11; 12]]
transpose matrix |> printfn "%A"   // [[1; 4; 7; 10]; [2; 5; 8; 11]; [3; 6; 9; 12]]
```

* O(n<sup>3</sup>) where n is the length of a square matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me get the assignment done.

If you don't mind some follow up questions, which purpose does the "[]" brackets you've placed serve and how do you determine exactly where to put them?

From what I could gather by playing around with the code for a bit, they seem necessary for 'yield' to be used in lists, and even though your positioning of them seem random to me, F# seems very picky about where I put them.

Comment: These are [list comprehensions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fsharp/fsharp_lists.htm). This particular example is a bit complicated because we have two nested comprehensions. You could rewrite the code to avoid them, but I find them elegant in many situations.

Answer (score 2):

For better performance, you can convert the list of list to an Array2D, and then create your transposed list from the Array2D.

```
let transpose' xss =
    let xss  = array2D xss
    let dimx = Array2D.length1 xss - 1
    let dimy = Array2D.length2 xss - 1
    [   for y=0 to dimy do [
            for x=0 to dimx do 
                yield xss.[x,y]
        ]
    ]
```

For non-learning purpose, you should use the built-int `List.transpose`

```
 List.transpose lst
```

Comment: I think this is missing a `yield`. Should be `for y=0 to dimy do yield [`.